# Is there alternative for “for loop” in pyspark

Tags: for-loop, pyspark, operators

I have a dictionary for which key containing 2 values as id key and value is a list of operators
now i have written a for loop to iterate over each id and key and check how many operators are there 
and as per the value of operator i am calling respective function and then finally union the result.

eq: id =1 , key = abc operators = [=,>,<]
for this id and key three function will get called equalsto, greater and less and the reurned output will finally get unioned.
 
this dictionary i have created from a dataframe.
 
is there any way i can avoid for loop here.
 
Note: - the funtcions are written to check values as per the operator signs
        eq.equalsto will check if the responded values is equals to the key condition or not

Comment: please share a sample of the dictionary and source dataframe along with expected output. it is hard to understand in the current format.